# SQL regex to identify alphanumeric values

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to exclude values like 3708.DK in sql. I'm using pattern like LIKE '%0-9.%' and '%[0-9.A-Z]%' and its not working .

Please suggest.

Comment: When you say "like," it is unclear exactly what is needed.  Will it always be four numbers followed by a dot and two uppercase letters?  If not, all possible permutations are needed.

Comment: always 4 numbers followed by a dot and then two uppercase letters

Comment: sorry, only sql server

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking...What's not working?  are you trying to use SSMS to replace values in a query? Or Is `3708.DK` a value stored in a table that you want to change?  Be aware, T-SQL doesn't natively support any kind of "regex", like C# or Python.

Answer (score 3):

If you're attempting to exclude rows in a table, then a [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) comparison would work.

Take this [minimally complete verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#LikeTest', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #LikeTest;

CREATE TABLE #LikeTest
(
    d varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #LikeTest (d)
VALUES ('this is a 3708.dk test')
    , ('this is another test');
```

Here's the pertinent bit:

```
SELECT lt.d
    ,  Match = CASE WHEN lt.d LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[a-z][a-z]%' 
                ESCAPE '\' 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM #LikeTest lt;
```

Results:

```
╔════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║           d            ║ Match ║
╠════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ this is a 3708.dk test ║     1 ║
║ this is another test   ║     0 ║
╚════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

The `LIKE` comparison above says "match where the data contains 4 consecutive digits, followed by a period, followed by two alpha characters in the range of `[a-z]`.  Be aware the LIKE statement is collation-sensitive; if you have a server or database collation that is case sensitive, my example `LIKE` won't match upper case alpha characters.  You can force a case-insensitive search by adding a `COLLATE` clause to the `LIKE` comparison, like this:

```
SELECT lt.d
    ,  Match = CASE WHEN lt.d LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[a-z][a-z]%' 
                ESCAPE '\' 
                COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM #LikeTest lt;
```